# Loop (while) into a loop (while) to do a query

Tags: php, sql

First the code:

```
while($thisValue = mysql_fetch_assoc($someUnrelevantPreviousQuery)) {
    if($thisValue['thisOne']=='something') {
         $query = mysql_query("Some query");
         $result = mysql_num_rows($query);
         if($result) {
             while($result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                 /* Do this */
             }
         }else echo "Error 1";
     }else
     if($thisValue['thisOne']=='something else') {
         $query = mysql_query("Some other query");
         $result = mysql_num_rows($query);
         if($result) {
             while($result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                 /* Do that */
             } 
         }else echo "Error 2";
      }             
}
```

So I have 1 problem and 1 question with this bit of code.

## Problem:

If the first while returns 2 values where `$thisValue['thisOne']=='something' AND $thisValue['thisOne']=='something else'`, it should do 2 queries. One for the first "if" and then one for the second. However, in practice, it will work find for the `$thisValue['thisOne']=='something'` but then the loop stops and does nothing for the other value. How comes?

EDIT:
Also if the first while only returns `$thisValue['thisOne']=='something else'` I get the "Error 1" echo, when it should proceed to the next if statement instead.

## Questions:

Is this the right way to do this? I mean should I use another loop or method?

**PS:** The code seems pretty self explanatory to me, that's why I didn't explain it.However if some details or anything is needed to a better understanding of it, please ask.

Comment: Second problem: you're using `mysql_*`, please... don't it's being deprecated. Also: it's a bad idea to mix `if (){}` curly blocks with `else [single-line-statements]`, which you're doing all over the place

Comment: Ya, I know, I know. I'm gonna change it to mysqli_*.

Comment: BTW: your first problem is an easy fix: `$thisValue['thisOne']` can never be equal to _both_ `Something` __AND__ `Something else`

Comment: If $thisValue['thisOne'] == 'something' of course the second if statement won't run. Because 'something' doesn't equal 'something else'. The only way you could get both to run is if somewhere in your first if statement you assigned $thisValue['thisOne'] to equal 'something else'.

Comment: What are your two SQL statements?  It feels like you're trying to do your joins programmatically, which is usually a poor choice (the database engine tends to run a _lot_ faster)

Comment: @Elias, @Aust: `$thisValue['thisOne']` is the content of the table's column `thisOne`, in a loop it can absolutely have more than one value.

Comment: @MiDo: Of course, that's why I took the precaution to check weather or not the variable was reassigned inside the loop(s) before posting that comment :) From what I gather, the OP expects both if's to be true (two query's) in one go, too... so regardless of this being a resultset, both if's can't be true at the same time

Comment: @MiDo It can have different values each time through the loop, but without another assignment it can't have multiple values in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your if statements:

```
if($thisValue['thisOne']=='something') {}
else if($thisValue['thisOne']=='something else') {}
```

It will only execute both blocks if "something" == "something else"

You're using "==" so it's *possible* for those values to equal each other ...But in most scenarios it would be highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seeing that my comment might just be the answer, I'll post it here:

You're checking the same variable (and therefore the same value) and expecting it to be equal to both `'Something'` *and* `'Something else'`. That kite will never, ever fly...

Perhaps change your second if from => to:

```
else
if ($thisValue['thisOne'] == 'Something else')
{}
//TO:
if ($thisValue['thisOne'] === 'Something else' || $thisValue['thisOne'] === 'Something')
{
    //do second query
}
```

That way the second query will run when the first if is true, but also when it's false, and the `$thisValue['thisOne'] === 'Something else'`. Also: in loosely typed languages, use `===` (type and value check) as much as you can. It's a good habit to get into.